# quotchap with biblatex title formatting

Tags: biblatex, quotchap

I am using the `quotchap` package which makes my chapters look like this:

[image]

I am using `biblatex` to generate a bibliography for my document like this:

```
\printbibliography[title={Bibliografie}]
```

The title of the bibliography is aligned to the right, but does not have the number like a normal chapter would. How can I arrange that?

Answer (score 3):

Use `\printbibliography[title={Bibliografie},heading=bibnumbered]`

By default the heading of a bibliography isn't numbered. So you have to change the definition.

For more details have a look at the documentation.

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Enjoy the whitespace}
text \cite{companion}

\printbibliography[title={Bibliografie},heading=bibnumbered]

\end{document}
```